# Analytic function and Taylor polynomials

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion, analytic-functions

Let $f\colon\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ , which is infinite time differentiable on $\mathbb R$. and $x_0$ $\in \mathbb{R}$ be any fix point.

Now, for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $x\in \mathbb{R}$ ,using Lagranges theorem on some specific function, we have:

$$
f(x)=f(x_0)+\dfrac{f'(x_0)}{1!} (x-x_0)+\cdots+\dfrac{f^{n}(x_0)}{n!}(x-x_0)^{n}+\dfrac{f^{n+1}(c)}{(n+1)!}(x-x_0)^{n+1}\text{ for some } c \in [x, x_0]\text{,}
$$

where $c$ is depends on $n$, $f$, $x$ , $x_0$.

Let

$$
T_{n}(x)=f(x_0)+$\dfrac{f'(x_0)}{1!} (x-x_0)+\cdots \ldots+\dfrac{f^{n}(x_0)}{n!}(x-x_0)^{n}
$$

and

$$
R_{n}(x)=\dfrac{f^{n+1}(c)}{(n+1)!}(x-x_0)^{n+1} \text{ for all } x \in \mathbb R\text{.}
$$

Now, for $n\in\mathbb N$ and $x$ $\in \mathbb R$  have :

$$
\implies f(x)=T_{n}(x)+R_{n}(x)\text{,}
$$

where $R_{n}(x)$ depends on $n$, $f$, $x$, $x_0$.

Now, from here I want to know what special property analytic function does have about $R_{n}(x)$.

What I am thinking is, if our $f$ is analytic at $x_0$ with radius of convergence $R'$, then

for any $x \in (x_0-R',x_0+R')$,

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}R_{n}(x)=0\text{.}
$$

Is my claim true? And what about converse, i.e., if $\lim_{n\to\infty}R_{n}(x)=0$ for all $x$ in some neighbourhood 0f $x_0$ then can we conclude that $f$ is analytic at $x_0$?

Comment: A real-valued function is analytic if and only if it has a convergent power series representation, which is the Taylor series if it is continuously differentiable. If I understand the question correctly, then it is true that for an analytic function $R_n(×) \to 0$. For the converse however, we may have $R_n(x) \to 0$ but the series may not converge (or may converge to something other than $f(x)$)

Comment: @Adam in the case of converse : since we have $f(x)=T_{n}(x)+R_n(x)$ ,how it can be converges to different $f$ .

Comment: @Adam since $f(x)-R_n(x)=T_n(x)$ so if $R_n(x) \to 0$ then clearly we have $f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}T_{n}(x)$. so i think converges of $R_n(x)$ gives us converse as well or am i missing something?

Comment: Sorry for misread, the converse should hold as well. If the Lagrange remainder $R_n(x) \to 0$, then the derivatives are bounded, i.e. for any compact $K \subset B(x_0, R')$ $\exists M > 0 s.t. \sup_{x\in K} |f^{(n)}(x)| \leq n! M^n$, which is a necessary and sufficient condition for real-analyticity. The important point I was thinking is that $R_n(x)$ does not necessarily tend to 0 in most cases, or that $T_n(x)$ may not converge.